# Where would be a good place to ask for tutorials?

Tags: discussion, support, ios-app

I'm sure that StackOverflow is not the right place to ask very broad questions as: how can I learn to... blah blah blah. But, I don't know if there is a place inside StackExchange where I can ask this kind of questions. For example:

Anyone know any iOS Auto Layout and Size Classes tutorial?

Comment: Probably on an internet search engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

None of the sites on the network accept questions like that one, but you might ask it in one of the chat rooms. Chats are run by community members, so each one has its own topic and rules. You should be able to find a few about iOS programming.